# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value username to data type int

Tags: sql, int, varchar

It's about an error in username. When I enter a username (sumitasharma) as a string it shows the below mentioned error.

In table definition, column datatype of Username is varchar(50). I'm entering username into a textbox and error occurs.

> Error in Line 67.
>      Line 65:     con.Open();
>       Line 66:     cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into register values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "','" + TextBox12.Text + "','" + TextBox13.Text + "','" + TextBox14.Text + "','" + TextBox15.Text + "')", con);
>       Line 67:         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>       Line 68:     }
>       Line 69:     protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Your question title is very confusing. `converting......to data type int`?

Comment: Right before like 67, output what your command text actually contains.  That's the TSQL that is running.  Edit the post to contain that code.

Comment: Instead of concatenating strings to get a SQL statement, you should be using [Prepared Statements with Parametrized Queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28with_Parameterized_Queries.29).